# How to create a database user for oracle 11g on windows 8?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle database and therefore is trying to follow the office guide. ([link to the guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#XEGSG110)) However, it seems that the guide is for Windows 7, so in step 2 - creating database user, it says:

> 1. Display the SQL command prompt window. For example, on Windows, click Start, then Programs (or All Programs), then Oracle Database 11g
>      Express Edition, and then Run SQL Command Line.

And in windows 8, there is not start button. I try to search the menu using keyword `oracle` but nothing with similar name is found. I tried to go to the Program Files directly but also no similar file found. So, how should I create a database user on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Windows 8, but I guess that it must have some kind of a "command prompt" (you know, a program that lets you perform *text-based (command-line) functions*; its window is black with white letters. Once opened, the cursor blinks at the prompt, waiting for your commands). Try to find it, run it.

Then you'll be able to connect to your database (you do have it installed, right?) as

```
C:\> sqlplus sys/your_sys_password@database as sysdba
```

You'll be connected as SYS (be careful! It is a powerful user and its misuse might break your database! I'd suggest you to create another user, for example "mydba", grant it DBA role and let it perform DBA actions).

If you're unsure of what your tablespaces are, run

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USER_DATA
APEX
APEX_9695076087226093

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

as you'll need at least two of them. Now create your new user:

```
SQL> create user mike identified by lion
  2  default tablespace user_data
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  profile default
  5  quota unlimited on user_data;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Granting *create session*, it'll be able to connect to the database, but won't be able to do anything else, so you'd have to grant it some more privileges (such as *create table, create view, create procedure* etc.).

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);
create table test (id number)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

Comment: Just in case for someone is looking at this answer and don't know how to open the command prompt: press windows button on the keyboard and type cmd, and you will find it.